# How to detect the library file by header file or name of function? And vise versa?

Tags: linux, function, header

I have a header file, for example "elf.h" or name of method, for example "ElfData::addToSection()".

I'd like to know the corresponding library file - the name of it and it's location, for example /usr/lib/libelf.a, or /usr/lib/libelf.so.0.8.13.
What are the ways to solve this problem. And what is the best way.

Also i'd like to know what headers, functions match to specified library file.
Operational system = Ubuntu Linux.

May be, these questions are stupid :) 
but I would appreciate it if you could reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For newer libraries, you can often use the [`pkg-config`](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/pkg-config/) tool. You give this the name of the package you want to link with and it gives you the appropriate compiler/linker options:

```
$ pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0
-I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include
$ pkg-config --libs glib-2.0
-lglib-2.0
```

so that you can put this in your `Makefile`:

```
LIBS = `pkg-config --libs glib-2.0` -lm      # link with glib and libm
CFLAGS = -O2 `pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0`
```

(It won't find the headers for you, just the include dirs.)

For libraries that do not support `pkg-config`, there's no single correct way of finding out the header that a library belongs to or vice versa. You normally either hand-code this knowledge into your build system, or use something like the [GNU autotools](http://www.openismus.com/documents/linux/using_libraries/using_libraries) that allow checking multiple libraries/headers for the identifiers or symbols you need.

Comment: Thank you for reply, Mr larsmans. I am not familiar with GNU autotools at all. It would be greate If you could demonstrate the example with "elf.h".

Comment: @LuckyMan: there's nothing to do with `elf.h` as it doesn't declare any functions. There is no library corresponding to it.